# socketError : Permission Denied

Tags: android, ssh, hdfs, protocols, cluster-computing

I tried to connect to hdfs cluster through android code.But i am facing the problem in socketError. Below i included log file and code.The connection is being established properly but there is a problem in creating a socket for connection.

```
Connect_Ssh:
DllDate: Aug 30 2017
ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.69
UnlockPrefix: Anything for 30-day trial
Architecture: Little Endian; 32-bit
Language: Android Java
VerboseLogging: 0
connectInner:
hostname: 202.53.13.23
port: 1032
sshConnect:
connectSocket:
connect_ipv6_or_ipv4:
ai_family: 2
ai_socktype: 1
ai_protocol: 6
socketErrno: 13
socketError: Permission denied
Failed to create socket for connecting.
--connect_ipv6_or_ipv4
--connectSocket
Failed to establish initial TCP/IP connection
hostname: 202.53.13.23
port: 1032
--sshConnect
--connectInner
Failed.
--Connect_Ssh
--ChilkatLog
```

Here is the code for which the above log file being printed.
Code:

```
package com.example.sunny.clusteraccess;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import com.chilkatsoft.CkSsh;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "Chilkat";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CkSsh ssh = new CkSsh();
    //  Any string automatically begins a fully-functional 30-day trial.
    boolean success = ssh.UnlockComponent("Anything for 30-day trial");
    if (success != true) {
        Log.i(TAG, ssh.lastErrorText());
        return;
    }
    String hostname;
    int port;
    //  Hostname may be an IP address or hostname:
    hostname = "202.53.13.23";
    port = 22;

    success = ssh.Connect(hostname,port);
    if (success != true) {
        Log.i(TAG, ssh.lastErrorText());
        return;
    }
    success = ssh.AuthenticatePw("student","kmit");
    if (success != true) {
        Log.i(TAG, ssh.lastErrorText());
        return;
    }
    Log.e(""+success,"");
    int channelNum;
    channelNum = ssh.OpenSessionChannel();
    if (channelNum < 0) {
        Log.i(TAG, ssh.lastErrorText());
        return;
    }
    success = ssh.SendReqExec(channelNum,"hdfs dfs -ls");
    if (success != true) {
        Log.i(TAG, ssh.lastErrorText());
        return;
    }
    success = ssh.ChannelReceiveToClose(channelNum);
    if (success != true) {
        Log.i(TAG, ssh.lastErrorText());
        return;
    }
    String cmdOutput = ssh.getReceivedText(channelNum,"ansi");
    if (ssh.get_LastMethodSuccess() != true) {
        Log.i(TAG, ssh.lastErrorText());
        return;
    }
    Log.e(TAG, cmdOutput);
    ssh.Disconnect();
}
static {
    System.loadLibrary("chilkat");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you give internet permission in your code?? Try to add this in your manifest
file if you did not do yet.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```